# Calculate Y position from latitude in degrees on mercator projection

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to calculate the Y position on a map with mercator projection given the latitude in degrees. Here's what I need:

```
//mapHeight might be 600 (pixels), for example
//latitudeInDegrees ranges from -90 to 90
public double CalculateY(double mapHeight, double latitudeInDegrees)
{
    //what on earth do I do here to calculate the Y offset on the map?
    return ???;
}
```

I've tried all sorts of things I've found online (including wikipedia and stackoverflow), but none of it has worked for me. I'm probably doing something stupid but I can't figure out what. Can anyone save my sanity?

Comment: Sorry for many edit. I created release version of my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public double CalculateY(double mapHeight, double latitudeInDegrees)
{
    return Math.Log(Math.Tan(latitudeInDegrees / 360d * Math.PI + Math.PI / 4));
}
```

Don't remember scale y with mapHeight (you should know max and min value of latitudeInDegrees for taht)

Quote from Wikipedia:

> At latitudes higher than 70° north or
>   south, the Mercator projection is
>   practically unusable.

You should write code like this:

```
private double CalculateYRelative(double latitudeInDegrees)
{
    return Math.Log(Math.Tan(latitudeInDegrees / 360d * Math.PI + Math.PI / 4));
}
...
minY = CalculateYRelative(MinLatitudeInDegrees);
maxY = CalculateYRelative(MaxLatitudeInDegrees);
...
public double CalculateY(double mapHeight, double latitudeInDegrees)
{
    return mapHeight*
           (CalculateYRelative(latitudeInDegrees) - minY) / (maxY - minY);
}
```

For more information:

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection)

[Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166059/how-can-i-get-latitude-longitude-from-x-y-on-a-mercator-map-jpeg)

[Same question 2](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080521142713AAnlVtI)

Comment: Your comment about scaling makes no sense to me. Can you please clarify? Once I know max and min latitudes, how do I use that to adjust according to the mapHeight?

Comment: Thanks so much. I had seen all your linked answers, but none explained sufficiently for me to get this working. Your edits helped me understand this.

Comment: @spanks, see my new edit. MinLatitudeInDegrees & MaxLatitudeInDegrees are your const. You should calculate minY & maxY with this const and use results in CalculateY. CalculateY returns value in [0, maxHeight]