# plotting latitude on to a (Mercator projection) SVG map

Tags: mapping, latitude-longitude

I want to convert (google sourced) **longitude and latitude** coordinates to **x and y** to place points on a **SVG map**

I can get the longitude converted to X but I can't nail latitude.

http://jsfiddle.net/chrisloughnane/an3BZ/17/

- red dots = place holders
- green dot = calculated position from longitude/latitude

I have read so much about Mercator projections and other projection systems API's I am now completely confused. I also followed Proj4JS library threads but couldn't find an example that was close to my task.

I attempted to emulate this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103924/mercator-longitude-and-latitude-calculations-to-x-and-y-on-a-cropped-map-of-the), unfortunately I got something wrong.

Could someone please have a look at my jsfiddle and see if it's an obvious mistake.

The second test **function secondconvert(latitude, longitude)** (bottom of javascript pane) provides me with a reasonably accurate **x coordinate** i.e. if I manually enter the **y coordinate** `b.ylat` change to `265` it covers my left red dot place holder nearly perfectly.

I think I'm close, any help would be really appreciated.

tia.

---

Original SVG from [here.](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ireland_trad_counties_named.svg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your calculations of `lattest` and `mapOffsetY` inside `secondconvert()` you're using variable `width` where Raphael's solution uses `worldMapWidth`. Fixing that you get closer to the expected result, though still not precise.

Comment: you **Sir are a star!** This was bothering me for a week. After correcting my error and then adjusting the southern latitude the results are accurate enough for the purposes of this project. Thank you very much for your help :P
http://jsfiddle.net/chrisloughnane/an3BZ/40/