# Given an image of a map convert an x and y coordinate to Latitude and Longitude

Tags: javascript, geolocation, projection

I have an image of a Mercator map (4000px by 2828px). I know that the longitude on the left is -170, the longitude on the right is 190, and the latitude on the bottom is 85.

I'm able to calculate the x and y given a latitude and longitude from the solution at [Mercator longitude and latitude calculations to x and y on a cropped map (of the UK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103924/mercator-longitude-and-latitude-calculations-to-x-and-y-on-a-cropped-map-of-the/10401734#10401734). However, I'm looking for the reverse. There are a few comments describing the reverse, but you do not get the same points if you go back and forth between the two equations.

Given an x and y pixel coordinate how do I calculate the latitude and longitude on the map?

Comment: This is a question for http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Javascript implementation on [this page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mercator#JavaScript).

You can use the Conv.m2ll() function:

```
var latlon=Conv.m2ll(pixel_x, pixel_y);
```

Comment: My longitude is offset. Longitude on the left is -170, the longitude on the right is 190. The latitude on the bottom is 85. How do I incorporate that into the equation?

Comment: So use lat=-85, lon=-170 (lon cannot be >180). BTW, that position sounds like somewhere near the south pole :-)